# redirect after add wishlist in opencart 1.5

Tags: opencart

I need to redirect to page `account/wishlist` after I added wishlist without click the popup button in `opencart 1.5`.

I think I need to add :

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/wishlist'));
```

but I don't know where I should put it.

Can somebody help me what should I do with this?

Thanks

Comment: if you have tried something, can you please include your findings too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect `account/wishlist` then open your `common.js` located on `catalog/view/javascript` and find `addToWishList()` function.

```
function addToWishList(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information').remove();

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#wishlist-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=account/wishlist'; // Add this line 
                location = url; // Add this line
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That is awesome hardik solanki. Thank you so much for your help.